# How can redux-form validation based on multiple fields be implemented?

Tags: validation, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Redux Form validation examples only include [individual field validations](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/tree/v2.4.5#synchronous-validation).

Having a list of a certain number of fields that are the same, how can I model a validation that requires at least one of the inputs to be a valid email address?

For example, for the given form made up of the following fields:

- User 1,
- User 2,
- User 3,
- Special User 4

How can I write a validation function that requires Special User 4 to always be set, and either one of the first 3 users?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your synchronous validation function is given all the values of the form. Your errors must correspond to a field key, or you can use the generic `_error` key, which will result in `this.props.error` being populated.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yup, that makes sense, thanks. I am able to send the error message from the validation function to the render function, but it's not clear by which condition this should show. I would need the general error to run ONLY if submit has been pressed. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Hmm... submit marks all the fields as 'touched', but there is currently no equivalent "show general error" flag beyond maybe anding all the touched flags together...

Comment: @ErikR. Lovely, this is exactly what I expected (the general error bucket to exist) and just googled for confirmation from the docs / here. This really is an excellent library, thank you :-)